# DocuSign connect event when a user has viewed the document

Tags: integration, docusignapi

I have been digging in the DocuSign Connect documentation and can't seem to find anything. I am wondering if there is a way to send out a Connect event when a recipient has viewed the DocuSign document. Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Recipient: Delivered status will fire the first time a particular signer views an envelope. Note that you can only track the first time a recipient views the envelope - further events won't fire if the user views the envelope multiple times.

More information is available in the Connect guide: https://docs.docusign.com/supportdocs/ndse-admin-guide/Content/custom-connect-configuration.htm

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot.